# Opencv mat truncates all double entries

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am populating my `cv::Mat matrix(size, size,  cv::DataType<double>::type);` (tried also `CV_64F` and `CV_64FC1` all yield same result). I am looping across `size` and doing this: `matrix.data[x*size+y] = someFunc();` where `someFunc()` returns a double. The problem is that for some reason the matrix truncates the double and stores only the integer part. For the sake of testing I created the following snippet

```
cv::Mat mat(10, 10,  CV_64F);
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i){
    for (int j=0; j<10; ++j){
        mat.data[i*10 + j] = 1.9;
        std::cout << double(mat.data[i*10+j]) << std::endl; // outputs 1
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I populate a `cv::Mat()` with doubles correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::Mat::data` is pointer to `unsigned char`. You have pay extra attention when accessing your data that way, i.e. cast it to double so that the offsets you add to it are correct.

The recommended way to access/modify elements of a `cv::Mat` is as follows:

```
cv::Mat mat( 10, 10, CV_64F );
mat.at<double>( y, x ) = 123.; // Careful y before x!
```

When you know the type of your data in advance you can use template-based `cv::Mat_`, which has several convenience `typedefs`. The above case could be rewritten to:

```
cv::Mat1d mat( 10, 10 ); // 1 - one channel, d - double
mat( y, x ) = 123.;
```

If all elements are set to the same value initially, you can also use;

```
double value = 1.9;
cv::Mat1d mat = value * cv::Mat1d::ones( 10, 10 );
```

but, of course, a double `for`-loop like the one you are using is fine, too.

And just to emphasize again, be careful with order of the `y`- and `x`-coordinates in the `(y,x)`-access operator above. I have too many people do it wrong and waste time over it.

Answer (score 1):

`Mat::data` is an `unsigned char*`. In your case it will be enough to cast it to `double` before accessing each matrix element:

```
((double*)mat.data)[i*10 + j] = 1.9;
```

and

```
std::cout << ((double*)mat.data)[i*10+j] << std::endl;
```

Notice this is slightly faster than using the `Mat::at()` accessor.

Comment: I doubt that, if it is a pointer to char, then `mat.data[x] = &mat.data[0] + x` since `&mat.data[0]` is char, I will advance `1byte * x` in the memory instead of `8byte * x` as I need...

Comment: `Mat::data` is of type `uchar*` and that is a fact.

Comment: You can learn more about how to access Mat elements [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html)